# How to create multiple entities of same type in a single go in CRM online?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am integrating MS Dynamics CRM online with my ASP.Net MVC application. I am creating a synchronization process between both. I'm stuck at the point where

1. I need to check if user has entered valid CRM credentials ie. server address, domain, username and password etc. I am not sure which class is to use for that?
2. I want to create multiple entities of same type in a single go in CRM online from my Application. Currently I am using ServiceProxy's `Create()` method to do so . How can I create , for instance, 10 contacts in a single request ?
3. Is there any way to send list of objects to CRM server and create
   them there?

Answer (score 2):

1. To check I believe the easiest way is just execute call for example of WhoAmI message. If it would not throw an exception - that will mean that credentials are correct.
2. You should look at [ExecuteMultiple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) message.